# How to automaticaly send ALL errors from javascript to Sentry?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sentry

I want to "automatically" sent all errors from my React project to Sentry, and i mean absolutely ALL, from the code, from React, from Promises.

Is it realistic to set it up?

By init:

```
    import * as Sentry from '@sentry/browser';
    Sentry.init({ dsn: 'https://<key>@sentry.io/<project>' });
```

Sentry handles only "uncaught exceptions and unhandled rejections"

From docs:

"**Automatically Capturing Errors**

By including and configuring Sentry, the SDK will automatically attach global handlers to capture uncaught exceptions and unhandled rejections."

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/#automatically-capturing-errors

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a custom utility that Will call the capture exception method of Sentry. A solution could be to add this method to an `ErrorBoundary`, and attach the custom method inside the `ErrorBoundary`, Just take into account that the `ErrorBoundary` should be your parent Component.

Check a post of the Sentry team that refers to your doubt [ErrorBoundary](https://blog.sentry.io/2017/09/28/react-16-error-boundaries).

[Error Boundary Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html)